# Increasing the length of the Description field in movement journal in AX 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, aot

How can we increase the field length of Description field up to 200 characters available in Movement Journal in Inventory module in AX 2009?

The field is InventJournalTable_DescriptionInventJournalTable(InventJournalTable).Description

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a new Extended Data Type of type String.
2. Set the StringSize property of your data type to 200.
3. Find the JournalDescription Extended Data Type in the AOT.
4. Change the Extends property of JournalDescription to the name of your new data type.
5. Synchronize the database.

Comment: And in some cases you should restart the AX client after you made this changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit standard EDT's by going to System Administration - Setup - System - Modify data types. There you can adjust the length of standard EDT's which cannot be adjusted otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The [InventJournalTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656152%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) has it's Description field of extended data type [JournalDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa599613%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) (String Size: 60).  Therefore open the AOT, Data dictionary and Extended data type branch, and find the JournalDescription entity, increasing it's string size to 200.  Sincronize...

And document your changes.

Comment: The StringSize property of JournalDescription cannot be edited, because it extends Description. I would not advise modifying Description, because many other data types extend it, and you may not want to change those fields unintentionally.

Comment: "...cannot be edited, because it extends Description."  I also agree that it is rare to make changes such a generic EDT.  I'll vote your answer up then :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the JournalDescription even in the AOT because other transactions will be affected. And you don't want to change the records of those transactions either. Think of the possibility that something will be affected once you change the length or any properties of a field. Best thing is, try to do it in the Test environment of your system.